# Is there any way to add custom property to a transceiver in Unified plan

Tags: webrtc

I'm having difficulty identifying which track belongs to which media source on the receiving end. In unified plan is there any way to define custom properties on a transceiver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having difficulty identifying which track belongs to which media source on the receiving end.

Use [`transceiver.mid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpTransceiver/mid) or the [`stream.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/id) of an associated stream to correlate tracks.

A transceiver has a `mid`, which is a unique id that is the same on both sides of the connection after initial negotiation. It is exposed here:

```js
pc.ontrack = event => {
  const track = event.track;
  const mid = event.transceiver.mid;
}
```

Alternatively, use `addTransceiver(track, {streams: [stream]})` or `addTrack(track, stream)` and use the `stream.id`:

```js
pc.ontrack = event => {
  const track = event.track;
  const id = event.streams[0].id;
}
```

> In unified plan is there any way to define custom properties on a transceiver?

*Any* JS object can have a property defined on it. But I suspect that's not what you mean.

`mid` and `stream.id`s are the only metadata negotiated over to the remote peer connection, and there's no official way to add custom ones.

Once a connection has been established, you can of course use a datachannel to send whatever data you want over.

#### How to hack custom metadata

OK there is a way, but I hesitate to show it, since you haven't said what you'd use it for. Please consider the above options before resorting to this. **Use at your own risk!**

You can add any number of `stream.id`s and replace them in the SPD with whatever you want:

```js
const config = {sdpSemantics: "unified-plan"};
const pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(config), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

const stream = new MediaStream();
pc1.addTransceiver("video", {streams: [stream]});
pc1.msg = "Hello";
pc2.ontrack = event => {
  pc2.msg = event.streams[0].id;
  console.log(pc2.msg);
};

pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = async e => {
  await pc1.setLocalDescription(await pc1.createOffer());
  let sdp = pc1.localDescription.sdp.replace(new RegExp(stream.id, 'g'), pc1.msg);
  await pc2.setRemoteDescription({type: "offer", sdp});
  await pc2.setLocalDescription(await pc2.createAnswer());
  await pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription);
}
```

I'm not actually recommending this, just showing it can be done. Any message you put in here is subject to SDP parsing rules, so be careful.

Comment: Is there any way to define new property to a transceiver.

Comment: Not officially, but I've included a way to hack it.

Comment: Yea, I have tried SDP hack method. But I heard that it is risky. I was looking for a method to add custom data to transceiver so that I can fetch on `pc.ontrack`event, something like `if (transceiver.cusomtProperty == 'something')  `

Comment: Thank you so much. I will go with `datachannel`.